# Logstash aggregation resets values

Tags: mysql, logstash

I am doing a simple logstash aggregation where I am checking specific values on a SQL table and whenever this value is being found I increase the counter. In the end I am just doing another simple division on how many times I have counted that value to all the values on that day to see a percentage. The date is my task_id.

From the logical point of view the percentage will drop from 100% and will go down until the date resets.

The aggregation works every time I let logstash run through the whole SQL table at once.

However, I does not work when logstash runs for a longer time and the SQL table gets constantly updated. Here I see that the percentage calculation is reset for some reason on the same day (I see 100% more than once per day).

I do not know why the calculation is reset. Any help will be appreciated.

Here is my complete logstash config:

```
input {
  jdbc { 
    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sql_failure"
    jdbc_user => "user"
    jdbc_password => "password"
    jdbc_driver_library => "D:\logstash-7.2.0\mysql-connector-java-5.1.40\mysql-connector-java-5.1.40-bin.jar"
    jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    statement => "SELECT id, date, failure FROM sql_failure WHERE id > :sql_last_value"
    use_column_value => true
    tracking_column => "id"
    }
  }

filter {
 aggregate {
    task_id => "%{date}"
    code => "
      map['count'] ||= 0
      map['failure_counter'] ||= 0

      map['count'] += 1

      if event.get('failure') == 1
        map['failure_counter'] += 1
      end

      event.set('failure_rate', ((map['count'].to_f - map['failure_counter'].to_f)/(map['count'].to_f))*100)
      "
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
  hosts => "localhost:9200"
  index => "failure"
  document_id => "%{uid}"
  }
}
```

Thats my pipeline.yml:

```
pipeline.id: sql_failure
pipeline.workers: 1
queue.type: persisted
path.config: "/logstash/failure_rate.config"
```

Comment: please consider giving a reproducible example

Comment: Did you run logstash with a different worker count? Running stuff like this often requires you to run only a single worker... you could also consider adding some information about your logstash config to your question.

Comment: @Daniel & @Nakx I added the informtion on logstash and pipleline config to my post. I wonder now if some of the configuration of the pipeline could be the culprit. As for example I do not configure `queue.checkpoint.interval`